# css faded border

Tags: css, image, border, gradient, fading

I'm trying to create a box with faded borders. I've managed to find so examples but I can't create what I hoping to accomplish.

```
    border:3px;
-webkit-border-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#382E5C), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
-webkit-border-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(#382E5C, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
-o-border-image:-o-linear-gradient(#382E5C, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
-moz-border-image:-moz-linear-gradient(#382E5C, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
```

That css give me cool fading borders on both side, but I also want the top border to stay a solid color. How do I make the top border solid, and keep the sides fading, transparent on the bottom.
 Thank You

Comment: Border-image affects the whole element. One suggestion is placing the element in another div, and set border-top:1px solid #000.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
if we use border-top the border will stay only in top place.

```
border-top: 3px solid red; 
/***
------add your fading borders
***/
```

if you not understand please give me your code...

Comment: I create another div with the border-top attribute, had to add margin-top:-3px; to get everything to line up correctly.